# Bootstrap 4 open multiple navbar dropdown without toggle

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 with multi level vertical sidebar menu. When clicked on any dropdown item the previously dropdown opened is closed automatically. PROBLEM: I do not want the previously opened dropdown to close itself. The user can open multiple dropdowns

Have tried few scripts to detect current nav-items with class show but no result.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-column w-100">
  <li class="nav-item ">
   <a href="#" role="button" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Data Entry</a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
     <a class="dropdown-item" role="button" href="/#">Add Job</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" role="button" href="#">Auto Upload</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" role="button" href="#">Manage Centah</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" role="button" href="#">Manage TGS</a>
   </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Data Entry</a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
     <a class="dropdown-item" role="button" href="/#">Add Job</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" role="button" href="#">Auto Upload</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" role="button" href="#">Manage Centah</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" role="button" href="#">Manage TGS</a>
   </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on a dropdown-item containing a checkbox the menu is closed.
The content of a dropdown-item is not handled by the plugin. No matter what you have inside dropdown-item clicking on it will close the menu.

You can track it here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21941